# Vagrant: How to create ONLY virtual Networks without starting Machines?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine

**Before** any virtual Machine is created, I want to make physical host pingable through IP address of virtual Network defined in `Vagrantfile`.

**Is there a way to avoid starting virtual machines and start only virtual network firs?**

Something like this:

```
vagrant up --networks-only
```

Comment: I added an [issue for Vagrant](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5923). **Any current workaround?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no light way and [nothing is planned](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5923#issuecomment-120487652).

### Heavy Workaround

- As [I mentioned there](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5923#issuecomment-120494734), create virtual machines and `halt` them just for the sake of creating virtual networks (networks are not removed when machines are `halt`-ed):

  ```
  vagrant up --no-provision && vagrant halt
  ```
- After that, when machines are actually required, just `up` them back with provisioning:

  ```
  vagrant up --provision
  ```

### Possible Optimization

If you have many virtual machines, specify *minimal* list of VMs connecting to all required networks. It appears that Vagrant does not create all necessary networks upfront until machines actually need them.